# Webdriverio RequestError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:9515 on virtual machine with azure pipeline but works locally

Tags: azure-pipelines, virtual-machine, webdriver-io, end-to-end

The test that is failing now used to work before when I used git artifact of the code repository on the dev azure pipeline to run a series of end to end tests on a target VMAgent. The tests themselves are run on the VMAgent targeting another VMTarget that has the environment for the tests.

However recently, we changed the way we copy the code for the End to End tests, moving from using the git artifact that copies the whole repository to using a powershell command to copy it directly from the proper pull request code available through the local network.

Now when I attempt to run the tests, webdriverio launches then stops with the following error:

```
##[error][0-0] [90m2023-07-18T14:24:03.954Z[39m [31mERROR[39m [97mwebdriver[39m: RequestError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:9515
[0-0]     at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (file:///C:/agents/a1/_work/r3/a/EndtoEndTests/node_modules/webdriver/node_modules/got/dist/source/core/index.js:790:107)
[0-0]     at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:628:26)
[0-0]     at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:525:35)
[0-0]     at ClientRequest.emit (node:domain:489:12)
[0-0]     at Socket.socketErrorListener (node:_http_client:494:9)
[0-0]     at Socket.emit (node:events:513:28)
[0-0]     at Socket.emit (node:domain:489:12)
[0-0]     at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:157:8)
[0-0]     at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:122:3)
[0-0]     at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21)
[0-0]     at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1278:16)
[0-0] [90m2023-07-18T14:24:03.955Z[39m [31mERROR[39m [97m@wdio/runner[39m: Error: Failed to create session.
[0-0] Unable to connect to "http://localhost:9515/", make sure browser driver is running on that address.
[0-0] If you use services like chromedriver see initialiseServices logs above or in wdio.log file as the service might had problems to start the driver.
[0-0]     at startWebDriverSession (file:///C:/agents/a1/_work/r3/a/EndtoEndTests/node_modules/webdriver/build/utils.js:68:15)
[0-0]     at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
[0-0]     at async Function.newSession (file:///C:/agents/a1/_work/r3/a/EndtoEndTests/node_modules/webdriver/build/index.js:26:45)
[0-0]     at async remote (file:///C:/agents/a1/_work/r3/a/EndtoEndTests/node_modules/webdriverio/build/index.js:48:22)
[0-0]     at async Runner._startSession (file:///C:/agents/a1/_work/r3/a/EndtoEndTests/node_modules/@wdio/runner/build/index.js:221:29)
[0-0]     at async Runner._initSession (file:///C:/agents/a1/_work/r3/a/EndtoEndTests/node_modules/@wdio/runner/build/index.js:187:25)
[0-0]     at async Runner.run (file:///C:/agents/a1/_work/r3/a/EndtoEndTests/node_modules/@wdio/runner/build/index.js:77:19)
Ended WebDriver sessions gracefully after a SIGINT signal was received!
```

What's odd is it seems to launch chromedriver properly but then can't seem to connect to the chrome instance. For example this is what is given before the error:

```
$ wdio run ./wdio.conf.ts --suite allTests
2023-07-18T14:23:53.9978984Z [1m[22m
2023-07-18T14:23:54.0020784Z [1mExecution of [34m1[39m workers started at[22m 2023-07-18T14:23:53.992Z
2023-07-18T14:23:54.0021388Z 
2023-07-18T14:23:57.0680081Z [90m2023-07-18T14:23:57.063Z[39m [96mINFO[39m [97mchromedriver[39m: Initiate Chromedriver Launcher (v8.1.1)
2023-07-18T14:23:57.0693491Z [90m2023-07-18T14:23:57.065Z[39m [96mINFO[39m [97m@wdio/cli:launcher[39m: Run onPrepare hook
2023-07-18T14:23:57.0750938Z [90m2023-07-18T14:23:57.071Z[39m [96mINFO[39m [97mchromedriver[39m: Start Chromedriver (C:\agents\a1\_work\r3\a\EndtoEndTests\node_modules\chromedriver\lib\chromedriver\chromedriver.exe) with args --port=9515 --url-base=/
2023-07-18T14:23:57.3548963Z [90m2023-07-18T14:23:57.351Z[39m [96mINFO[39m [97mchromedriver[39m: Starting ChromeDriver 114.0.5735.90 (386bc09e8f4f2e025eddae123f36f6263096ae49-refs/branch-heads/5735@{#1052}) on port 9515
2023-07-18T14:23:57.3562720Z [90m2023-07-18T14:23:57.352Z[39m [96mINFO[39m [97mchromedriver[39m: Only local connections are allowed.
2023-07-18T14:23:57.3575982Z [90m2023-07-18T14:23:57.352Z[39m [96mINFO[39m [97mchromedriver[39m: Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.
2023-07-18T14:23:57.3636765Z [90m2023-07-18T14:23:57.360Z[39m [96mINFO[39m [97mchromedriver[39m: ChromeDriver was started successfully.
2023-07-18T14:23:57.4223373Z [90m2023-07-18T14:23:57.419Z[39m [96mINFO[39m [97m@wdio/cli:launcher[39m: Run onWorkerStart hook
2023-07-18T14:23:57.4265335Z [90m2023-07-18T14:23:57.421Z[39m [96mINFO[39m [97m@wdio/local-runner[39m: Start worker 0-0 with arg: run,./wdio.conf.ts,--suite,allTests
2023-07-18T14:24:01.5459692Z [0-0] [90m2023-07-18T14:24:01.540Z[39m [96mINFO[39m [97m@wdio/local-runner[39m: Run worker command: run
2023-07-18T14:24:03.6585235Z [0-0] [90m2023-07-18T14:24:03.654Z[39m [96mINFO[39m [97mwebdriver[39m: Initiate new session using the WebDriver protocol
2023-07-18T14:24:03.9285990Z [0-0] [90m2023-07-18T14:24:03.924Z[39m [96mINFO[39m [97mwebdriver[39m: [POST] http://localhost:9515/session
2023-07-18T14:24:03.9327145Z [0-0] [90m2023-07-18T14:24:03.924Z[39m [96mINFO[39m [97mwebdriver[39m: [33mDATA[39m {
2023-07-18T14:24:03.9344554Z [0-0]   capabilities: {
2023-07-18T14:24:03.9362287Z [0-0]     alwaysMatch: {
2023-07-18T14:24:03.9375727Z [0-0]       browserName: 'chrome',
2023-07-18T14:24:03.9391229Z [0-0]       'goog:chromeOptions': [Object],
2023-07-18T14:24:03.9407653Z [0-0]       acceptInsecureCerts: true
2023-07-18T14:24:03.9422889Z [0-0]     },
2023-07-18T14:24:03.9434693Z [0-0]     firstMatch: [ {} ]
2023-07-18T14:24:03.9449146Z [0-0]   },
2023-07-18T14:24:03.9463625Z [0-0]   desiredCapabilities: {
2023-07-18T14:24:03.9475838Z [0-0]     browserName: 'chrome',
2023-07-18T14:24:03.9488775Z [0-0]     'goog:chromeOptions': { args: [Array] },
2023-07-18T14:24:03.9499955Z [0-0]     acceptInsecureCerts: true
2023-07-18T14:24:03.9511889Z [0-0]   }
2023-07-18T14:24:03.9521261Z [0-0] }
```

I tried the following steps provided by chatgpt with no luck:

```
1.Ensure Chromedriver is installed: Make sure you have the latest version of Chromedriver installed and it is compatible with your Chrome browser version. 
    
2.Check Chromedriver path: Verify that the path to Chromedriver is correctly configured in your test configuration file (wdio.conf.ts). Ensure that the path points to the correct location of Chromedriver executable on your system.  
    
3.Verify Chromedriver version: Double-check that the version of Chromedriver you have installed matches the version specified in your test configuration. If they don't match, update either the Chromedriver or the configuration to ensure compatibility.
        
4.Verify Chromedriver port: By default, Webdriver.io uses port 9515 for Chromedriver. Make sure there are no conflicts with other processes running on that port. You can try changing the port number in your configuration file to see if it resolves the issue.
        
5.Check for conflicting services: If you are using any services or frameworks that interact with Chromedriver, such as Selenium Grid or Docker, ensure that they are properly configured and not causing any conflicts.
    
6.Firewall and antivirus software: Check if your firewall or antivirus software is blocking the connection to Chromedriver. Temporarily disable them and try running the tests again to see if the issue persists.
        
7.Restart your machine: Sometimes, restarting your computer can resolve networking-related issues that might be causing the connection problem.
```

I tried running tests that i know work with the old setup and now they no longer work either, which to me means something is broken in the VM's environment?

What else could I try for this to work?